# Stopping certain MS Word styles from wrapping around embedded objects

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, styles

I have quite a long Word 2010 document that (for the sake of the purposes of this question) contains 1 Heading Style used repeatedly, 1 Body Text style used repeatedly, & numerous Visio objects.  When new visio objects are entered, I change the Layout Wrapping style from the default "In line with text" to "Square", with Left horizontal alignment.  Exactly as intended, this allows the body text to flow to the right of the visio objects.  All good.

Now, what I want to prevent, is heading styles from flowing to the right of these visio objects.  In other words, whilst I am chopping and splicing in one part of the document, should a Heading style elsewhere happen to find itself alongside a visio object, I want it to appear beneath the object instead.  - So body text flows alongside, but a header automatically drops down to underneath.

I've tried playing with the pagination settings in the paragraph settings of the Heading styles but not surprisingly these are not the answer.  Is there an option for this that I've missed (either in the style-paragraph settings, or the format-object settings) or does anyone have any ideas on how I might "trick" a solution (obviously without entering carriage returns manually, or anything equally asinine - the point is it's a big document that is frequently edited, and the corrections need to be fully or semi automated).  The best I can come up with is writing and periodically running a macro to check and correct, but that introduces a considerable number of it's own problems.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered adding the headings to a textbox?

Comment: @Adam yes, for quite a long time as at one point I too was convinced this might be a suitable workaround.  Unfortunately it didn't work - text boxes set to "inline" will still sit alongside the diagrams, and "Square" or "Tight" allows them to ride under or over the diagrams.

Comment: You're right, good point but I think a table will work! See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found you can achieve this by adding the heading text to a table with the table preferred width set to 100%. This leaves the table inline but won't allow any graphic to be to the left or right of the heading. Of course you can set the table appearance so the table itself is not noticeable.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in accepting this.  It didn't *quite* work in all scenarios so I left it to see if I could find a perfect answer.  Turns out this is as close to a perfect answer as I can find :)